# Create a random customer number and display it in a textbox

Tags: c#, random

im totally stuck here on creating a random number. Ideally not the same number twice as its a customer number.

I then need to display it in my tb_id (textbox) and write the line into a customer file.

Any help here would be great.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    **var rng = new Random();**
    // Here I need to write the random number (it's a customer number) to the tb_id text box. so I'm able to write it to their customer file afterwards.

    try
    {
        string fileName = string.Format(tb_surname.Text);

        if (tb_firstname.Text == "" || fileName == "" || tb_postcode.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Missing values from textboxes!");
        }
        else if (File.Exists(fileName + "Text"))
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("Warning: There is already a file with the surname you enter already on the system. Contents will be replaced - do you want to continue?", "File Demo", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question,
                 MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1, MessageBoxOptions.DefaultDesktopOnly) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                //write lines of text to file
                StreamWriter outputStream = File.CreateText(fileName + ".Txt");
                outputStream.WriteLine(tb_firstname.Text);
                outputStream.WriteLine(tb_surname.Text);
                outputStream.WriteLine(tb_surname.Text);
                **outputStream.WriteLine(tb_id.Text);**
                outputStream.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Text saved to file successfully!");
                this.Close();
            }
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

part 2

```
       // creating a random number here for the customer id
        Guid g = Guid.NewGuid();
        tb_id.Text = g.ToString();
```

to write Guid number to a text file.

```
        outputStream.WriteLine(tb_id.Text);
```

Comment: Why aren't you using a database?

Comment: due to the task requirements set. In an ideal world i guess a database would be better.

Comment: Would be dup of plenty of question how not to use `new Random` if it would not be so wrong usage of random numbers. Random numbers are never guaranteed to be unique, so you are likely looking for something else...

Comment: and why does the number have to be **Random** instead of sequential?

Comment: well it doesnt, just unique i guess.

Comment: Probably best to use something sequential if it doesn't have to be random.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would not recomend using the random number if you want to get it unique for users there is a high probability of getting different users with same number.

guid is probably better idea

```
  Guid g = Guid.NewGuid();
```

Comment: thankyou! is there any way to limit the amount of numbers i produce, as its huge. Guid g = Guid.NewGuid();
            tb_id.Text = g.ToString();

Comment: i guess it would be Guid g = Guid.NewGuid(1,1000);
            tb_id.Text = g.ToString(); for example to give a number between 1, & 1000

Comment: @JamesWozencroft no, Guids are always 32 hex digits.  You shouldn't worry about the size anyways.

Comment: A guid has to be large in order to decrease the statistical chance of getting a duplicate.

Comment: @ebyrob Depends on how many customers he has. Once you get past 77000 customers, you'd have a 50% chance of a collision. 1% chance after just 9300. Don't use hash codes for anything except what they where designed for: balancing hash tables.  Required reading: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/03/22/socks-birthdays-and-hash-collisions.aspx

Comment: @allen.mn  [Statistical rancomness is not what makes GUIDs unique](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/06/27/8659071.aspx)

Comment: @SamIam - Thank you! I misunderstood what makes GUIDs unique.

Answer (score 1):

First off, If you're just using random numbers to identify users, than Use a GUID like COLD TOLD said.

**unique** and  **random** are completely different things

---

but for the sake of understanding how to use random numbers...

declare `rng` as type `Random`

To actually create the random number, type something like

```
int randI =  ng.Next(0, 1000);
```

which will get you a random number between 0 and 1000.

You can use Intellisence to see what other options you have as far as random numbers go.

to put that number in your text box, than do

```
textBox1.Text = randI.ToString();
```

Comment: thanks for the understanding, works great. Just need it to write to my text file now, outputStream.WriteLine(tb_id.Text); as that doesnt seem to work.

Comment: the number doesnt appear in my text file when i check. i used the Guid method.

Comment: @JamesWozencroft can you post code of how you're setting `tb_it.text` in the question.  Can you also post the code of how you're generating the `Guid`?

Comment: @JamesWozencroft  I don't see the specific problem with what you have.  You should probably use the debugger to see what's going on

Comment: ok thanks. its not throwing up any errors at all.  and the application is running as it should. Just that its not writting the number. I will have a look around. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Guid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.aspx) Structure. A GUID is a globally unique identifier and it is provided in the .NET framework

```
 this.iD = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
```

Comment: You could just do "outputStream.WriteLine(id.Text);" as you had in your code.

Comment: outputStream.WriteLine(tb_id.Text); i have just tested that and doesnt seem to work when i check my file.